# iText7 : truncate contents only if multiple line text

Tags: itext, itext7

I am developing iText7 application and I am trying to add a text in a rectangle.

I am reading [this article](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement), I would like to add a text in the condition below.

- If the content is a multiple line text as `Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \n Multiple Line Text` (has new line in the text), the content longer than rectangle width should be truncated width dot-dot-dot as `Fig.1`.
- If the content is a single line text as `Single Line Text Single Line Text Single Line Text` (no new line in the text), the content longer than rectangle width should **not** be truncated and should be wrapped to the next line as `Fig.2`.
  [image]

Can I do this with iText7?

Comment: Yes, you can introduce your own `IRenderer` implementation, and replace the default renderer for an object with your own renderer. Which Object do you want to show this behavior? A `Paragraph`? A `Cell`? Note that writing your own renderer requires knowledge of the inner workings of iText. Because of that, it's possible that you won't get an answer on Stack Overflow, but that you'll have to post the question on the closed ticketing system reserved for paying customers.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for reply. I add a text with `Paragraph`.

Comment: In that case, you need to examine the [ParagraphRenderer](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7J/repos/itextcore/browse/layout/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/layout/renderer/ParagraphRenderer.java) and override at least the `layout()` and `getNextRenderer()` method. You'll see that a `LineRenderer` is used to render the different lines of content stored in the `Paragraph`. You'll probably also have to create your custom `EllipsedLineRender` to draw the line exactly the way you want. Looking at the `ParagraphRenderer` code, you'll get a fair idea of the complexity of your project.